# pause button when pressed again to resume reloading view controllers

Tags: iphone

I am using `AVAudioplayer` to **play audio files**, **play/pause button to toggle between play and pause** and `NSTimer` with `audio player` to synchronize `view controllers` one after another. I have a total of 10 or 11 `view controllers` to load one after the other.

When play button is pressed the very first time it starts `NSTimer`, starts playing an `audio file` and based on `NSTimer`, view controllers will load one after the other.  When pause button is pressed again to resume it resumes everything from that point audio file, `NSTimer` and `view controllers` from the same point where it was paused which is good. However, at the same time it starts loading the `view controllers` again one after the other from the beginning based on `NSTimer` which is not good.

It is reloading view controllers with this statement

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
```

So my issue is that I need to stop the loading of `view controllers` again from the beginning when pause button is pressed again to resume playback.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{ 
    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [audioPlayer pause];
        [self pauseTimer];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
    }       
}

-(void)pauseTimer{
    pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
    previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
    [timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

-(void)resumeTimer{
    float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
    [timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
    [pauseStart release];
    [previousFireDate release];    
}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{  
    First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
    firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];  
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];    
    [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];    
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];    
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
    [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
    [firstController release];   
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     
 }
```

Can anyone give an idea on how to stop the loading of `view controllers` again from the beginning when pause button is pressed again to resume playback.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're trying to display `FirstViewController` after 11 seconds have elapsed in the audio track. 
You can set you timer up to poll (every .5 - 1.0 seconds) and if the audioPlayer's elapsed time is greater than 11.0, perform your action.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{ 
if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){
   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   [audioPlayer pause];
   [self.timer invalidate]; // stop the polling timer
} else {
   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [audioPlayer play];
   // start/resume the timer
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 /* polling interval */
                                                      target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(tryToDisplayViews:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES]; /* REPEAT = YES */
}       
}

// the new polled method
-(void)tryToDisplayViews:(id)sender {
    // need last current time as a new variable to ensure that we only add the view once
    // and not every time the method fires with currentTime > 11.0
    if( audioPlayer.currentTime > 11.0 && lastCurrentTime < 11.0) {
        [self displayviewsAction:nil];
    } 
    // you can add the second view here in a similar fashion
    // if(audioPlayer.currentTime > (23.0+11.0) && lastCurrentTime < (23.0+11.0) ) {}

    lastCurrentTime = audioPlayer.currentTime;

}
```

This also get's rid of your `resumeTimer`/`pauseTimer` actions, you don't need to count the time paused.