# Expected expression missing in If else else if statements

Tags: iphone

I am **trying to solve my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034544/pause-button-when-pressed-again-to-resume-reloading-view-controllers)**. So i thought maybe with if else if else statement can solve my problem.

But i think i m missing expected expression in below if else else if statement.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{
    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){       
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [audioPlayer pause];
        [self pauseTimer];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];
    }  
    else if
    {
        [audioPlayer play];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                        target:self
                                        selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
    }    
}
```

Any idea what i m doing wrong over here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `else if` before the `else` block.  And `else if` is a secondary conditional, it requires some kind of boolean statement following it like a normal `if`, such as `![audioPlayer isPlaying]`.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your code, so I can't provide any more advice beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

use it in this way

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{
     if([audioPlayer isPlaying]){       
       [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"]          forState:UIControlStateSelected];
      [audioPlayer pause];
      [self pauseTimer];
} 
else if(put your condition here)
{
    [audioPlayer play];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}   
else {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    }   
}
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: by doing this it loses toggling functionality

Comment: no your code just missing some thing your condition is not correct please cross check to your condition

Answer (score 0):

How can you have if ... else ... elseif?

Is your code not just in the wrong order? 
Pretty sure you can't have an elseif of an else.

if elseif else?