# Multiple methods: Target and Selector of button not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Trying to solve my [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034544/pause-button-when-pressed-again-to-resume-reloading-view-controllers). This time trying this way
Added multiple methods to one button but when clicking on button it does nothing looks like those methods are not working.

```
//Add Play Button

UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playpauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playpauseButton];


- (void)playAction:(id)sender{
[audioPlayer play];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
}  

-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
        if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [audioPlayer pause];
            [self pauseTimer];
    } else {     
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];  
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                        target:self
                                        selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];   
        }         
}

 -(void)pauseTimer{
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
-(void)resumeTimer{
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
[pauseStart release];
[previousFireDate release];
}
```

It shows play button when clicking on it nothing happens. It should play the audio file, start the NSTimer, start loading views and toggle between play and pause button. Any idea what is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the user taps the button, the `playAction:` calls `[audioPlayer play]`.
Immediately afterwards, the `playpauseAction:` evaluates `[audioPlayer isPlaying]` to `YES` and does `[audioPlayer pause]`.

Comment: No it is not pausing the audio player because then it should show the pause icon which is not happening.

Comment: @user1452248 you set "Play Icon.png" for UIControlStateSelected in the same branch of your if statement.

Comment: ok now i have switched the order of methods [playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; [playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; and now it is playing the audio file toggling between play pause button but now pause button is not toggling back to play button if you press again to resume

Comment: I honestly think your current method is a little contrived. I would remove the playAction: method, since the playpauseAction: does almost exactly the same thing, and add if(!pauseStart)return; at the beginning of resumeTimer:

Comment: Please check i edited my post may be you will get my real problem i m having.

Comment: I answered your previous question, you're trying to synchronize the displayed view with the audio file right?